# How to default to the default argument in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

So lets say I've got a function:

```
def print_something(a, b, c='something', d='something else'):
    print '{}/{}/{}/{}'.format(a, b, c, d)
```

And I've got this method:

```
def print_method(self, a, b):
    if self.c and self.b:
        print_something(a, b, self.c, self.d)
    elif self.c:
        print_something(a, b, c=self.c)
    elif self.d:
        print_something(a, b, d=self.d)
    else:
        print_something(a, b)
```

Is there a way to get the same functionality as `print_method()` without having to provide an if for each possible combination of self.c and self.d?

Comment: what are self.c and self.b?

Comment: They could be many things. Maybe strings that are initially empty but may be appended to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a dictionary to the function call containing keyword argument names and values. So something like this should work:

```
kwargs = dict((k, getattr(self, k)) for k in ('c', 'd') if getattr(self, k))
print_something(a, b, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change your other function setting values to empty strings so the default will be used unless we get non empty strings passed in:

```
def print_something(a, b, c="", d=""):
    c = 'something' if not c else c
    d = 'something else' if not d else d
    print('{}/{}/{}/{}'.format(a, b, c, d))

def print_method(self, a, b):
        print_something(a, b, self.c, self.d)
```

Or more concisely as you consider any falsey value to be false in the if checks in your class we can use `c =  c or default`

```
def print_something(a, b, c="", d=""):
    c = c or 'something' 
    d = d or 'something else' 
    print('{}/{}/{}/{}'.format(a, b, c, d))
```

Comment: i always like the the more concise `c = c or 'something'` formulation.

Comment: @acushner, yes I have a bit of a mental block when it comes to using that but yes it will work , I will add it

Comment: I feel the `x if x else y` construct is more idiomatic.

Comment: @AndrewGorcester, I feel more comfortable using it too but I suppose in this case they are equivalent as we are not checking ` if x is not None` etc..

Answer (score -1):

You could use `**args` here:

```
def print_method(self, a, b):
    extra_args = {}
    if self.c:
        extra_args['c'] = self.c
    if self.d:
        extra_args['d'] = self.d
    print_something(a, b, **extra_args)
```

This calls `print_something()` with however many extra arguments you have.

Comment: This won't do the right thing.  Because if self.d is set, but self.c is not, positionally, c will be assigned self.d, which seems counter to what the questioner desires.